# is mitmproxy a real proxy/reverse proxy?

Tags: python, networking, reverse-proxy, infrastructure, mitmproxy

I used mitmproxy's reverse proxy plugin with some extra logic which would be hard to implement in nginx for example (not just some request/response modification). And I love it for it's simplicity. However, I lack the deeper knowledge of inner mechanics of proxies and reverse proxies. I would like to use mimtproxy for production and in general as part of infrastructure logic.

**Question**:

Can mimtproxy be used like that or it is just pseudo proxy/reverse proxy for testing and examining traffic?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: @KlausD. Does not lie the answer for my question in mitmproxy's source code and design?

Comment: Please explain the difference between a `pseudo proxy` and a `real proxy`. As the difference between those definitions is crucial for an potential answer without knowing this detail the question can't be answered in my opinion.

Comment: I explained that I do not have deeper knowledge of its mechanics. But if you need to know the difference - can I throw out my traefik and put there mitmproxy?